# Why Java SDK DriverManager.registeredDrivers takes instances from function registerDriver() instead of just using the instances created by Iterator?

Tags: java, jdbc, spi

I'm learning the Java SPI for JDBC driver.

in a simple word, jdk has an interface `Driver`, anyone can provider their own JDBC services impl, for example, mysqlJDBC, ProsgresJDBC.
Now when we try to use any service like getConnection(), `DriverManager` in sdk will scan all the Driver impl under `META-INF` folder and invoke each impl constructor. Invoking each impl class means loading the class file. During the class loading, all of the JDBC providers have a line in their class static block like

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
```

to put their created instance like `ProgresDriver` into a list field *registeredDrivers*.
Then jdk can call `someDriver.connection()` to get a conn.

My questions is, however, I realized the instances created by the `ServiceLoader.Iterator.next()` are not used anywhere.

```
                    try {
                        while (driversIterator.hasNext()) {
                          //my questions is here, jdk didn't take the return instance
                          driversIterator.next(); 
                        }
                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        // Do nothing
                    }
```

while they provide a public method registerDriver() like above mentioned,

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(Driver toBeAddedDriver);
```

which basically add the instance into the *registeredDrivers* list

```
registeredDrivers.addIfAbsent(new DriverInfo(driver, da));
```

then why not jdk just use the instances created by the iterator like this?

```
                    try {
                        while (driversIterator.hasNext()) {
                          Driver nextDriver = driversIterator.next(); 
                          registeredDrivers.addIfAbsent(new DriverInfo(nextDriver, da));
                        }
                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        // Do nothing
                    }
```

Is there anything I misunderstood? Thank you for explaining!

Comment: Your description is erroneous. Loading the class does not constitute creating an instance or invoking the constructor. The static init block is run when the class is loaded. No instance is created yet.

Comment: @user207421 Could you make an Answer of your Comment? Maybe add a bit more discussion. This is an interesting and  educational topic.

Comment: Well I think the OP can answer his own question. There are several other false statements in his question: for example the scan takes place during `DriverManager` initialization, not during `getConnection()`. He should have another *good* look at the source code. The purpose of the apparently pointless `hasNext()/next()` loop is clearly explained in the source code comments. @BasilBourque

Comment: @user207421 Loading the class of course does not constitute creating an instance or invoking the constructor. I guess you misread it. My statement is the opposite. "Invoking each impl class means loading the class file". invoking constructor -> loading class file -> static code block runs -> jdbc has instances creation in static code block.

Comment: @user207421 the scan takes place at ```ensureDriversInitialized()``` inside the ```getConnection()``` of the driverManager, not sure what u mean by "DriverManager initialization".